# Excel Add-in changes the file name to the add-in`s name although it should not

Tags: vba, excel

I need your help regarding an add-in I created using VBA, then I saved as add-in to be able to use on all Excel workbooks and also send it to my friends.

The add-in simply saves the printed area in the active sheet as a PDF file with the same name of the workbook, it saves the PDF to the desktop and works fine as a macro.

But when I save as PDF and use it, it saves the PDF file with the same name of the add-in, not as the workbook`s name.

Any suggestions?

The VBA code is:

```
Sub Save_as_pdf()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim s(1) As String
Dim sNewFilePath As String

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    s(0) = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    If FSO.FileExists(ThisWorkbook.FullName) Then
        '//Change Excel Extension to PDF extension in FilePath
        s(1) = FSO.GetExtensionName(s(0))

        If s(1) <> "" Then
            s(1) = "." & s(1)
            sNewFilePath = Replace(s(0), s(1), ".pdf")

            '//Export to PDF with new File Path
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=sNewFilePath, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        End If
    Else
        '//Error: file path not found
        MsgBox "Error: this workbook may be unsaved.  Please save and try again."
    End If

    Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use ThisWorkbook.Name (because if the code executed is the add-in, this workbook is the add in) but rather ActiveWorkbook.Name

Comment: it just worked perfectly, thank you very much :)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I've added an answer as a community wiki - if you want to post your comment as an answer to receive the deserved votes/points I'll remove this one.

Comment: Thank you @SOofWXLS, no worries leave it like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on Matteo NNZ's comment above:

`ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook in which the code is currently being executed from (in this case, the add-in)

`ActiveWorkbook` refers to the workbook that is currently active within the same instance of Excel.